# Textbox on frontpage

Tags: boxes, titles

in my thesis I would like to include a "textbox" in the lower left corner of the front page. It should contain the names of my supervisors. But I'm not able to put a box there, I suppose it has to do with the "rules" of the class etc. Does anyone have a way around or...?

This is how I start things off:

```
 \documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
 \begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \title{\vspace{-10mm} \textbf{{\huge Header\\      SubHeader\\ \vspace{3mm} Thesis \\}}
 \author{Mememe}
 \date{\today}
 \maketitle
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `titlepage` environment, which provides a whole page for the title.  The formatting is up to you.  Here is an example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{5cm}
  \begin{center}
    \Large\bfseries
    Header\\
    SubHeader\\
    Thesis\par
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \begin{center}
    \large Mememe
  \end{center}
  \vspace{2cm}
  \begin{center}
    \date{\today}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{2cm plus 1fill}
  \begin{flushleft}
    Supervisor: XXXXXXX\\
    Committee member: YYYYYYYY
  \end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```